# Wireless bridge with separate LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

I want to set up a wireless bridge between two routers, keeping a separate LAN for the connecting router, but I’m running into some trouble. The situation is as follows:

```
ISP <-> modem <-> router A <-> router B <-> LAN
```

1. The modem and router A are not under my control. I can’t configure them, only connect to router A.
2. Moreover I don’t want devices on router A to be able to connect to the devices on the LAN of router B. Preferably, router A only notices one connected device.
3. As a further restriction, the connection between router A and router B can only be wireless.

I have tried to set up bridge mode on router B, and while it could connect to router A, it seems to violate the second restriction.

Is this setup possible at all? If so, what are the keywords to look for (apparently not “bridge”)?

Comment: What are the models and model numbers of the two routers? In dd-wrt what you are trying to accomplish is client mode, which uses wireless as the WAN connection, and would firewall the lan from the first routers subnet. But the real question here is.... Why are you stealing your neighbors internet? ;-)

Comment: Bridge-mode on most devices means that it is "bridging" or combining two lans together. I.e router a & b will be on the same subnet, with no NAT in-between.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’ll look that up. My router is a Netgear R6400, the other one an Astoria VGV7519. I recently moved into an apartment and my neighbor explicitly granted me access (even sent me the SSID and password). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most consumer grade routers will not have the function you seek. Your going to need a new router. You can take a peek at the compatibility list for dd-wrt here: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/List_of_DD-WRT_firmware_supported_devices

This brings up an issue, if you don't get a router with two physical wireless interfaces you won't have wireless on LAN-b (you could use the Netgear for this) but I frown on needlessly running two devices when one can handle the task. I wouldn't recommend repeater mode on the same physical interface. I have had terrible experiences with atheros, broadcom & ralink based routers trying to bridge & repeat on the same interface. Just get a dd-wrt router with two physical interfaces. (Two wireless radios). A good for instance is the Netgear wndr4300 (version 4)